# What version of Google Analytics works on iOS 6?

Tags: ios, analytics

I'm still supporting iOS 6 on my apps, and I was going to update Google Analytics, but CocoaPods gives me an error saying it requires a higher version.

What is the last version of Google Analytics that works with iOS 6 and how do I get it?

Comment: iOS6 was a very long time ago. Why not upgrade to at least iOS7 upwards? I stopped supporting iOS7 in my apps already.

Comment: There's nothing in my app to prevent it from working on iOS 6.  I just dropped iOS 5 due to a third party requirement for iOS 6.  I'm a firm believer in backwards compatibility.